# Richtexbox text style corruption when minimized

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I'm using richtexbox component as message history panel. Message consist of header (printed red and old) and the body on new line.

It works using this code:

```
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Bold);
richTextBox1.AppendText(header);    
richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
richTextBox1.SelectionFont = new Font(richTextBox1.SelectionFont, FontStyle.Regular);
richTextBox1.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + text + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine);
```

Everything works OK when window is active. But messages added in time, when the window is minimized have corrupted font style and color. In most cases it looks like as body uses header style.

Answer (score 0):

resolved by using the combination of

```
richTextBox1.Update(); 
richTextBox1.DeselectAll();
```